# Bot Framework Card with form fields

Tags: c#, botframework

I like would to ask how is it possible to put a Card with fields like text a box, on a chat bot.

thanks in advance.

Please see sample image attached.

[image]

Comment: ow sorry, I found the answer. I will use this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots 

3rd day botframework Developer.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ow sorry, I found the answer.

Just use

Adaptive Cards. - learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots.

3rd day being a botframework Developer.. :-)

Comment: Yup. www.adaptivecards.io -> great design tools

Comment: But limited given the channel you will use. be careful

Comment: @NicolasR Thanks for the advice.